# Why Memory allocation failed whe HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile using libhpdf?

Tags: pdf, png, libpng, libharu

I got a exception ERROR: error_no=1015, detail_no=0 using HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile to load a png file with a jpeg file extention.I have libpng and libpng-dev installed. I can not figure out why this exception occurs. Anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL,I had compile libaru demo already....thanks stackoverflow..and libharu developer.

ERROR: error_no=1015, detail_no=0

general , you must check your image file weather or not exist in current directory.

indicate you c program want to load  something isn't exist.

Good luck.