# libharu memory allocation failed while loading image

Tags: c, libharu

I have some C code trying to use libharu. Although I can use every function of this library (even UTF8) I can hardly draw images. Here is some very basic code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include "hpdf.h"

jmp_buf env;

#ifdef HPDF_DLL
void  __stdcall
#else
void
#endif
error_handler  (HPDF_STATUS   error_no,
                HPDF_STATUS   detail_no,
                void         *user_data)
{
    printf ("ERROR: error_no=%04X, detail_no=%u\n", (HPDF_UINT)error_no,
                (HPDF_UINT)detail_no);
    longjmp(env, 1);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    HPDF_Doc  pdf;
    HPDF_Font font;
    HPDF_Page page;
    char fname[256];
    HPDF_Image image;

    strcpy (fname, argv[0]);
    strcat (fname, ".pdf");

    pdf = HPDF_New (error_handler, NULL);
    if (!pdf) {
        printf ("error: cannot create PdfDoc object\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* error-handler */
    if (setjmp(env)) {
        HPDF_Free (pdf);
        return 1;
    }


    font = HPDF_GetFont (pdf, "Helvetica", NULL);


    page = HPDF_AddPage (pdf);

    HPDF_Page_SetWidth (page, 550);
    HPDF_Page_SetHeight (page, 500);

    image = HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile (pdf, "img.png");


    HPDF_SaveToFile (pdf, fname);


    HPDF_Free (pdf);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this I have `ERROR: error_no=1015, detail_no=0`. I have found a similar post in stackoverflow: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771205/why-memory-allocation-failed-whe-hpdf-loadpngimagefromfile-using-libhpdf). However although original poster said the problem is solved it hardly helped mine. I moved img.png to a folder and recompiled the file. Changed the code that says `/home/name/path/to/img.png` which is the direct path to image. Nothing works. I "always" have the same error, but when I change the name of file I have `ERROR: error_no=1017, detail_no=2` which basicly means program cannot find image (according to reference of libharu) So I deduce that program finds img.png; but, it's strange but, cannot allocate the necessary memory. Which is weird because I cannot see any reason for this program not to allocate memory. I have every kind of permission.

I am using GCC 4.7.2 under Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal and libharu 2.3.0 RC2. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Insterestingly, under Windows 7 using MinGW exactly the same code above compiles without any problem. I really wonder what am I doing wrong under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Equalities of polynomials .

I also encountered the same problem when i integrated the `haru sdk` in my macOS environment.

The `error_handler` returned `ERROR: error_no=1017, detail_no=2`,and then i checked the official document for `haru` at http://libharu.sourceforge.net/error_handling.html query `0x1017` indicates that the file failed to open, so i suspect that the  **second parameter** of the `HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile` method needs to pass an exact **png image file path**, so after I modified it, the problem was solved, and I hope to help you.

code ad follow:

```
char filename1[255];
strcpy(filename1, "/Users/xx/Downloads/lusaceg.com.png");
image = HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile (pdf, filename1);
```

Faithfully yours.